# How often should a litter box be cleaned?

Tags: cats, toilet-training, cleaning

I have 2 cats, and 2 litter boxes. We do them when they seem full, but I'm wondering, should we do them more often than that? At what intervals, if I have 1 litter box per cat, should I clean their litter boxes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rule of thumb: **number of litter boxes = number of cats + 1**.

You should add 1 additional box to the 2 already present, boxes should be cleaned once to twice a day. Cats are clean and therefore like clean boxes to soil in.

Wash entire box once a week: remove litter, wash box and refill.

Comment: Once or twice a day? My gosh; I currently am more on a 1 or twice a week.

Comment: Scoop daily and full clean (remove all old litter, wash box and refill) once a week. :)

Comment: Think of it as a toilet for us, when poo's are in the toilet we would rather flush it before using it ourselves. I don't normally humanize our pets but this is one of those situations that we have in common.

Comment: Yes, you need to clean the litter boxes once or twice a day.

Comment: You might be able to make do with just 2 boxes. We have the same setup and our experience is that if we don't dig up their shit twice a day they stop covering it. Which is good incentive to do it regularly...